# Firebase RTDB full text search with Typesense

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, typesense

does Typesense support firebase RTDB? I know it works with firestore. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Typesense is a totally independent service. All you need to do is add data in it irrespective if which database it is coming from.

You can use [Firebase Realtime Database Triggers for Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events) to run a function whenever data is added to RTDB and then update it in Typesense. It just the pre-made extension that works with Firestore but you can always write yours as mentioned.